# Calendar workflow starttime not pulling

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I created a sp designer workflow that creates a library based on an event, with some specific format: YYYYMMDD-EventTitle.

The first time I did the workflow I did it as a list workflow and it worked fine.
However to be able to deploy it to production I had to redo it again as a reusable workflow.

The reusable workflow works fine, but the document libraries are created always with the following format: 00010101-[eventtitle] and not correctly as: 20120325-eventtitle

Update1: I changed a little bit and put another log to history. TO see the result, please see the second image.

[image]
[image]

Comment: its the same exact workflow, the only difference its reusable. !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching for a little while, I need to say that this is a bug in the product.
I could prove it my self here:

[Calendar workflow in sharepoint designer, cant pull Start Time column](http://levalencia.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/calendar-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-cant-pull-start-time-column/)

The solution is:

So, I decided to give it a try to workaround, AND THIS SHOULD NOT BE THE WAY TO DO IT, MICROSOFT.
1.  Just find the current item ID, and then get the start time.

Guess what, see my workflow history list, and it works

Comment: Wow that is weird... good find!

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the start time with a reusable workflow?